# ZX Spectrum fuse-emulator - how to use loader/multi-file program?

Tags: emulation, zx-spectrum

I'm using [fuse-emulator](http://fuse-emulator.sourceforge.net/) on Ubuntu. In a book of type-in programs, some are spread across multiple files. There is a "loader" (usually setting up graphics or some machine code parts) which ends with `load ""`. On cassette, this would then load then next program that would normally be the main code for the program.

Is there a way to accommodate this in Fuse? I've tried replacing the empty string with the name of the next file to load but Fuse seems to get stuck and repeats "Program: (original program)".

I save/"compile" the listings to `.TAP` format using zmakebas utility.
As an example

```
10 PRINT "loader program"
20 LOAD "part2"
```

saved as "part1.bas", converted to .TAP with
`zmakebas -a 10 -n "part1" -o "part1.tap" part1.bas`

and

```
10 PRINT "main program"
20 PRINT "finished"
```

saved as "part2.bas" and converted with
`zmakebas -a 10 -n "part2" -o "part2.tap" part2.bas`

but I can't seem to get the second file to load.

Comment: If you're using the zmakebas that's in the Ubuntu repo, it has an unpleasant [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zmakebas/+bug/1908289) that incorrectly translates user functions. The code looks perfect, but won't run

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order for the program to load in one go without having to open a new file for each section, you'll need to combine them into a single .tap file. Happily, the .tap format is designed to make this easy - concatenating two files together results in a valid file. So, after creating part1.tap and part2.tap with zmakebas as above, you can combine them with:

```
cat part1.tap part2.tap > final.tap
```

Comment: A nice and straightforward solution, have tested after finishing the type-in program and it works as expected.